# Adjust nth-child properties when hiding a column

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

We're using jQuery DataTables to display some table data.  We're also using the "Show / hide columns" option  dynamically (https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html)

The issue is we're using CSS `nth-child` logic to align/format some columns, but when we hide a column with jQuery, all the `nth-child` logic is now off by the column that was hidden.

Please [see this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jbrquo6u/) for demonstration of the problem.

Is there a way to adjust all `nth-child` css values?

Comment: Please include your code in the question itself. There is a reason you were warned about linking directly to JSFiddle without providing code, and placing "Please see the JSFiddle" within a code block to bypass this goes against Stack Overflow's rules. I've taken the liberty to comment out the JSFiddle link from your question and remove the fake code block.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly, there is nothing wrong with posting a jsFiddle link in the question when the question is detailed enough, [proof](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151616). It's not recommended to use it as the only source in the answer though.

Comment: After seeing the fiddle I cannot understand why you want to use a `nth-child` selector and not a simple class reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

Avoid using `nth-child` in this case. Instead assign class names to the columns with [`columns.className`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.className) and target specific columns using class names instead.

**JavaScript**

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "columnDefs": [{
        "targets": 3,
        "className": "col-age"
    }]
} );
```

**CSS**

```css
#example td.col-age {
  text-align:right;
}
```

> **DEMO**

See [updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jbrquo6u/2/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Yes - and thumbs up for `"className": "col-age"`, this is how it should be done.